# Discrete Math: Ways to Prove Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The point of mathematical induction is to prove $\forall x\geq b[P(x)]$ by instead proving $P(b)\wedge \forall x\geq b[P(x)\rightarrow P(x+1)]$ ($b$ is often, but not always, $0$ or $1$). However, there are many other statements that are equivalent to these two. Which of the following is NOT equivalent to these two statements?

Answer Choices:

1. $P(b)\wedge P(b+1)\wedge P(b+2)\wedge \dots$
2. $P(b)\wedge P(b+1)\wedge \forall x\geq(b+1)[P(x)\rightarrow P(x+1)]$
3. $P(b)\wedge P(b+1)\wedge \forall k\geq 0[P(b+2k)\rightarrow P(b+2(k+1))]\wedge \forall k\geq0[P(b+2k+1)\rightarrow P(b+2(k+1)+1)]$
4. $P(b)\wedge P(b+1)\wedge \forall x\geq(b+2)[P(x)\rightarrow P(x+1)]$

Comment: It's interesting to note that, in Peano arithmetic, (1) is *not* equivalent to the given statement. In a non-standard model of arithmetic, the statement (1) could be true, yet there still be a "transfinite" number for which $P$ isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All but $4.$ are equivalent and they are also equivalent to $4. ∧ P(b + 2)$

Comment: You were right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only stating the answers. Please convince yourself!

1. Equivalent.
2. Also equivalent.
3. Equivalent. This is a restatement by splitting into the 2 cases where k is even or odd.
4. Not equivalent. P(b+1) true does not imply P(b+2) is true.